# Configuring different authorization/authentication schemes

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am implementing security on an ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 application, which is used as a Web API. I am trying to understand if and how to implement 2 different authentication schemes.
Ideally, I would like to allow authentication via Azure Active Directory or via username/password for specific back-end services that contact the application.
Is it possible to configure ASP.NET Core for such a setup where an endpoint either authenticates through Azure AD or JWT token?

I tried with something like this, but upon calling the generate token endpoint, I get a 500 with absolutely no information. Removing the Azure AD configuration makes the endpoint work perfectly:

```
services.AddAuthorization(configuration =>
{
    configuration.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());

    configuration.AddPolicy("OpenIdConnect", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAD:ClientId"],
    Authority 
        = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] 
        + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
    SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
});

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        IssuerSigningKey = TokenAuthenticationOptions.Credentials.Key,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidAudience = TokenAuthenticationOptions.Audience,
        ValidIssuer = TokenAuthenticationOptions.Issuer
     }
});
```

Comment: You need a Cookie Authentication for OpenIdConnect Authentication. Like this https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/OpenIdConnectSample/Startup.cs#L71

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. You wrote, "where an endpoint either authenticates through Azure AD or JWT token..." For the JWT token part, where does the user get the JWT token? For the through Azure AD part, do you mean to redirect the user to Azure AD when the user lacks a token?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin the AAD token must come from AAD, yes, the app should redirect them. The JWT token is generated at an endpoint (Controller Action) I created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` constant when you add the authorization policy and when you add the authentication middleware.

Here you are using `OpenIdConnectDefaults`. Good. Keep that line.

```
services.AddAuthorization(configuration =>
{
    ...

    configuration.AddPolicy("OpenIdConnect", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // keep
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
 });
```

Here you are using `CookieAuthenticationDefaults`. Delete that line.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ...

    SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme // delete
});
```

Why?

When your OpenIdConnect authorization policy runs, it will look for an authentication scheme named `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. It will not find one, because the registered OpenIdConnect middleware is named `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. If you delete that errant line, then the code will [automatically use the appropriate default.](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L25-L26)

### Edit: Commentary on the sample

#### A second reasonable solution

[The linked sample application from the comments](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs#L38) calls `services.AddAuthentication` and sets `SignInScheme` to "Cookies". That changes the default sign in scheme for all of the authentication middleware. Result: the call to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is now equivalent to this:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions 
{
    SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
}
```

That is exactly what Camilo had in the first place. So why did my answer work?

My answer worked because it does not matter what `SignInScheme` name we choose; what matters is that those names are consistent. If we set our OpenIdConnect authentication sign in scheme to "Cookies", then when adding an authorization policy, we need to ask for that scheme by name like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(configuration =>
{
    ...

    configuration.AddPolicy("OpenIdConnect", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) <----
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

#### A third reasonable solution

To emphasize the importance of consistency, here is a third reasonable solution that uses an arbitrary sign in scheme name.

```
services.AddAuthorization(configuration =>
{
    configuration.AddPolicy("OpenIdConnect", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Foobar")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

Here you are using `CookieAuthenticationDefaults`. Delete that line.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    SignInScheme = "Foobar"
});
```

Comment: If that's the problem, then why every single Microsoft article and GitHub repo I found is setup like that?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could you please link an example MSFT article or GitHub repo setup. That way I can respond to your comment.

Comment: Sure, see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs#L38

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That samples does use the "Cookie" sign in scheme. I've updated my answer to show that it is not so much the name of the scheme that matters but instead consistency in naming that does.

Comment: The problem was in fact buried in a middleware, your first solution (which I had tried before) made me realize that. Thanks

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Cool. I encourage you to post your own answer that indicates the solution that my answer helped you to find. That might help others in the future and I would find it interesting.

Comment: I normally would, but the solution was a bad custom middleware done by a rookie, so it won't actually help someone

Comment: `SignInScheme` denotes the middleware used to persist the OpenIdConnect identity, hence using cookie is correct. You've confused `SignInScheme` with `authenticationScheme`, the name of which the configured OpenIdConnect middleware gets associated with.