# Specifying an authentication scheme for a single route that's handled by middleware

Tags: authentication, jwt, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1, hotchocolate

I have a new ASP.Net Core 3 MVC site that I've added GraphQL to with [HotChocolate](https://hotchocolate.io/).  I have users signing in to the MVC side using cookie-based auth with Auth0:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
        {
            ...
        });
```

But for GraphQL requests, I need JWT auth, for which I'd use:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(config =>
        {
            ...
        });
```

They both independently work fine.  Cookie auth allows controller use; JWT auth allows GQL use.  But I can't figure out how to get the cookie auth for the controllers and JWT for the `/graphql` route.

*A little context: HotChocolate uses a custom middleware to handle requests that come in to the `/graphql` route.  It's not on a controller, so I can't just specify the scheme with the `Authorize` attribute as there isn't a controller to put it on.*

#### Similar questions

- [Combining cookie and token authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776410/combining-cookie-and-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core)
   - The answer here ("use a framework") is vague and fairly unhelpful.
- [Configuring different authorization/authentication schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312503/configuring-different-authorization-authentication-schemes) - This is .Net Core 1.1, not 3.1.  The APIs have changed quite a bit.  Tried to adapt it, but got runtime errors saying `DefaultSignInScheme` is required.

(There were a few others, mainly focused on combining REST and MVC, but these both go to controllers so the scenario is a bit different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, so I thought I post my solution in case others may have the same problem.

Hot Chocolate uses the Default Authentication Scheme so in Startup I declare JWT as the default:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    })
```

And everywhere I need Cookie Authentication I simply add:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: did you use the aspnet core's authorize? or the hot chocolate's one?

Answer (score 2):

I had a quite similar issue and I wanted to share my solution. In my case, I wanted to have both authentication schemas applied to my HotChocolate api. I was able to do this for normal controller endpoints by adding this attributes:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer" + "," + "OpenIdConnect")]
```

For having both schemas applied to my HotChocolate graphql endpoint I did this trick in my Startup

```
       endpoints.MapGraphQL().RequireAuthorization()
            .Add((endpointBuilder) =>
            {
                var authAttribute = endpointBuilder.Metadata.SingleOrDefault(x =>
                    x is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute);
                if (authAttribute != null)
                    ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute) authAttribute)
                        .AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer" + "," +
                                                 "OpenIdConnect";
            });
```

Comment: I believe this works by effectively adding an `AuthorizeAttribute` with the default authorization policy and authentication scheme to the GraphQL endpoint, then finding that attribute and modifying the authentication schemes on it.

That should be fine if you want all requests to the GraphQL endpoint to be authorized, but it won't be suitable if you need to allow anonymous access to certain fields (such as a sign in mutation, for example).

Comment: It can also be simplified by specifying an `AuthorizeAttribute` with the required schemes in the `RequireAuthorization` call:

`endpoints.MapGraphQL().RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute { AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,OpenIdConnect" });`

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from IgnacioMir's answer above, I think I've finally found what feels like a reasonably elegant way of doing this.

Assuming that you want to use Cookie authentication for most of your site, but some other scheme (e.g. JWT bearer tokens) for your Hot Chocolate endpoint, then you can define your authentication schemes with Cookie authentication as the default as normal:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(...);
```

Then add both an [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and an [`AllowAnonymousAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to the GraphQL endpoint:

```
app.MapGraphQL()
    .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
    })
    .AllowAnonymous(); // Adds AllowAnonymousAttribute to the endpoint metadata
```

This overrides the default authentication scheme for the GraphQL endpoint without ASP.NET enforcing any authorization checks.

In other words the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` ensures that the authorization checks are left to HotChocolate's own authorization middleware, which is especially important if you only want the checks to be applied to fields marked with HotChocolate's [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/custom-attributes/#authorizeattribute).

Comment: should the query file's Authorize attribute change as well? If so can you please share the change as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: No there's no need to change anything with the `HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute` attribute. In the project I used this approach on, the `Authorize` attribute is applied to the subset of fields (properties) on the Query class that require authentication.

Comment: did you do any changes to the addAuthorization part as well? could you please share a sample of it?

Im trying to use Azure AD instead of Cookie authenticate in this case

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do this.  I ended up just splitting it into two projects.  One provides the GraphQL API and the other provides the website.  Doing this, each can have their own auth scheme.